# How to Add spaces between a string in Java?

Tags: java, string

I have a string like

```
String str = "A1HighriseA22-5sty.Elev.A3Elevator(s)A4WalkupA5RowHouseA6DetachedA7Semi-DetachedA8TownHouse";
```

the requirement is I need to add space before and after A1, like wise i need to do it for all the A's listed in the string (like space before and after A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8). I am not sure whether it is possible or not. If yes, can you please help me on how to do that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `String.replaceAll` that accepts a regex, then just a capture group and add the spaces around

```
String str = "A1HighriseA22-5sty.Elev.A3Elevator(s)A4WalkupA5RowHouseA6DetachedA7Semi-DetachedA8TownHouse";
String result = str.replaceAll("(A\\d)", " $1 ");

//A1HighriseA22-5sty.Elev.A3Elevator(s)A4WalkupA5RowHouseA6DetachedA7Semi-DetachedA8TownHouse
// A1 Highrise A2 2-5sty.Elev. A3 Elevator(s) A4 Walkup A5 RowHouse A6 Detached A7 Semi-Detached A8 TownHouse
```

If you go to more than `A9`, you the muldi-digit regex

```
str.replaceAll("(A\\d+)", " $1 ");
```

Comment: Thanks Azro!!!. I have a another problem like 
String str = "A1HighriseA22-5sty.Elev.?Elevator(s)A4WalkupA5RowHouseA6DetachedA7Semi-DetachedA8TownHouse";
Instead of A3, i need a space before and after ? can you please tell me how to do that along with the previous question??

Comment: @Gopi use the pipe `|` to make an OR : `str.replaceAll("(A\\d|\\?)", " $1 ");`

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str1 = "A1HighriseA22-5sty.Elev.A3Elevator(s)A4WalkupA5RowHouseA6DetachedA7Semi-DetachedA8TownHouse";
    String str=""; 
    for(int i=0;i<str1.length();i++){
        if(str1.charAt(i)=='A' && (str1.charAt(i+1)=='1' || str1.charAt(i+1)=='2' || str1.charAt(i+1)=='3' || 
        str1.charAt(i+1)=='4' || str1.charAt(i+1)=='5' || str1.charAt(i+1)=='6' || str1.charAt(i+1)=='7' ||
        str1.charAt(i+1)=='8' || str1.charAt(i+1)=='9')){
            str+= " "+str1.charAt(i)+""+str1.charAt(i+1)+" ";
            i++;
        }else{
            str+=""+str1.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str);
```